# Uglify for CSS and Gulp

Tags: css, gulp

Im using gulp uglify to uglify my JS.

What should I be looking for to do the same thing with my CSS?

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: google has about 2726151526262 results for 'uglify css gulp' maybe one of them is enough for you? Pick the second: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cssmin

Answer (score -1):

If you're just looking for a compressor, [CSS Compressor](http://csscompressor.com/) works.

And something like [CSS Unpacker](http://cssunpacker.com/) to reverse the process.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Glorfindel totally understand your point about link-only answers...but honestly, what else would you provide here? I would contend that the "essential parts of the answer" and resource titles/links are one and the same.

Comment: The question should be closed - questions asking for off-site resources are off-topic on StackOverflow. There's [another StackExchange site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) to ask these kind of questions.

Comment: @Glorfindel 100% agree with that. And it's easily Google-able. I just stumbled onto his question, though, and use those two resources on a regular basis, so I thought I'd share. Not sure why my response got downvoted, as opposed to the Q itself.

Comment: You have enough privilege to post comments on questions, that is a better option in this case. By the way, I didn't downvote your answer.

Comment: @Glorfindel Oy, yes! My apologies, that sounded like it was directed at you. I meant that as a general aside, not towards you specifically.